# Import DB2 files to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, import, db2-luw

Given the DAT file and the DDL file for each table in a DB2 database, can I import this data to SQL Server? I have no access to the original server or any copy of a DB2 server so connecting to a live instance isn't an option.

Can I do this without a live instance of DB2 or should I go back to the client and ask for CSV files? Is there a procedure or tool that makes this process smoother? I've tried to find a file-based connection string to use to connect to a set of DB2 files with no luck. I've also tried SwissSQLDB2ToSQLServer and SqlLinesData to see if they have a file-based option built in.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the DAT file? Is this the actual table space container?

Comment: Yes, I have a dat file that appears to contain the actual data and a ddl file that appears to contain the table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given the comment above, you can't import DB2's container files (DAT, LRG, or anything else) directly. You need a CSV or equivalent. Yes, one way to get this is run the `EXPORT` utility on a live DB2 database. HTH!